# Deleting the rest of the lines in a text file after a line contains a specific string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, text-files

I have a text file (incoming_orders.log) that is being written to by an api and I need to keep all the orders that come in before a certain time while incoming_orders.log is still being written too.

example of incomimg_orders.log:

OrderId=1,Time=13:02:04,Quantity=7,Part=8

OrderId=2,Time=13:04:47,Quantity=16,Part=1

OrderId=3,Time=13:05:00,Quantity=5,Part=2

OrderId=4,Time=13:05:01,Quantity=86,Part=11

OrderId=5,Time=14:58:04,Quantity=21,Part=19

OrderId=6,Time=14:22:40,Quantity=7,Part=32

OrderId=7,Time=16:15:17,Quantity=7,Part=32

OrderId=8,Time=16:21:23,Quantity=7,Part=32

OrderId=9,Time=16:35:44,Quantity=7,Part=32
...

I need to get all the orders at or before 13:05:00 and write them to a new file;

I have tried the following, but it only gets rid of OrderId 4 and keeps the rest

```
string newFile = @"path.log";
string incoming_orders = @"incoming_orders.log"

var oldLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(incoming_orders);
var newLines = oldLines.Where(line => !line.Contains("Time=13:05:01"));

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(newFile, newLines);
```

Please let me know what else I can add for clarification.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `var newLines...` line to this:

```
var newLines = oldLines.Where(line => line.Split(',')[1].CompareTo("Time=13:05:01") < 0);
```

Given the sample lines above, that resulted in the following new file content:

```
OrderId=1,Time=13:02:04,Quantity=7,Part=8
OrderId=2,Time=13:04:47,Quantity=16,Part=1
OrderId=3,Time=13:05:00,Quantity=5,Part=2
```

Comment: That is great, it works on test data, I'll find out how it works once the real data is coming into the file.  I understand what you did with the Split and CompareTo methods.  I am struggling with the [1] and == -1.  Do you have a resource or explanation you can point me to?

Comment: Sure. The `[1]` means the second item in the array resulting from the split. C# arrays are zero-based, so OrderId is `[0]`, Time is `[1]`, Quantity is `[2]`, etc. As for the `== -1`, that's just the funky way that the String.CompareTo method works. Documentation for that is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx -- and in retrospect, it should probably use `< 0` instead of `== -1`...

Comment: Yes, absolutely it should use `< 0` rather than `== -1`. Documentation says that `CompareTo` returns a value < 0; it doesn't specify `-1`.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Fixed now.